# What are the dimensions of the steel in the concrete slabs on the upper floors of my house?

Tags: concrete, ceiling, slab

Drilling holes (for curtains) in the ceiling of the 1st floor(2nd floor in the US) of my house  I ran into a steel rod in the middle, running parallel to the outer wall.  The steel is about 2.5cm in and starts one meter from the side wall.  So far, it's at least a meter long. (I drilled three holes and all three hit it.)

Is this a rod and how thick is it?  Can I assume that I can drill a few centimeters to either side and not hit it?

(I'm assuming that I can't/shouldn't try drilling through it)

(This is in the Netherlands and the house is from 1985 if it matters)

Comment: It's either a) rebar, which is something you probably don't want to drill through, but likely won't destroy the structure or b) it's prestressed/pretensioned concrete, in which case it's a rod or cable under immense tension and cutting through it will potentially cause catastrophic structural issues.

Comment: @DA01 any idea how thick either of these would be?

Comment: I think it can vary wildly depending on the structure.

Comment: maybe to clarify.  The metal doesn't seem to be there 10cm from either side of the room.  I drilled those two hole 1st to 4.5cm, tied a string between them and started drilling along that line.  the next 2 holes from the one side also didn't hit the metal and the 3rd one did.

Answer (score 2):

It's a piece of metal that sits on top the window sills to either side(10cm) and into the room about 5cm.

I ended up just drilling another hole 2 cm out from the original holes and it wasn't there.

I guess it's something to keep the weight off of the window frame.